# is requirements.txt more reliable than Pipenv?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, requirements.txt

I am in this weird dilemma and not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a project with 10s of pip packages managed through Pipenv. It worked fine for many days. but now a dependency for one of the packages was updated and my code started breaking.

lets say Pipfile has two packages in my Pipfile (pinned versions)

```
abc = "==1.0.0"
pqr = "==2.0.0"
```

both abc and pqr use another package as a dependency say `xyz` which is not listed in my Pipfile and has no control over which version gets installed.

Now when my CICD runs the next time, the latest version of `xyz` is installed which breaks my code.

had I used `requirements.txt` by doing `pip freeze` it would have pinned the version of all the packages, including `xyz` in `requirements.txt` and this issue would not have occurred.

So, does this mean requirements.txt gives you a more deterministic environment if we pin the versions? I have read a million times Pipenv is supposed to be the more deterministic between the two, but in my case, that is not working.

Point 2:

In my CICD, if I use

`pipenv install --ignore-pipfile`

I am guaranteed to get the pinned versions. but then next time when I do

`pipenv install <NEW_PACKAGE>`

pipfile.lock gets overwritten and the latest version of package which might break my code would sneak in.

Given this I have 2 questions:

1. am I using Pipenv incorrectly or misunderstood how it's supposed to be used?
2. what can I do to get the deterministic environment if the dependency of the package in Pipfile gets updated and break my code.

Thanks.

Comment: "Now when my CICD runs the next time, the latest version of `xyz` is installed which breaks my code." – Does *your code* or *your dependencies* depend on  `xyz`? Is there a reason why `xyz` isn't fixed when that seems to be required by your application?

Comment: I am not explicitly installing this dependency through Pipfile. one of the package is installing it for me.

Comment: and the worst part is I have 232 dependencies in my requirements.txt and many of them have changed so it's hard to know which one to fix.